# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Конусные краны до диаметра 24̋  с необходимой автоматизацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, здесь запятая не нужна (честно говоря, не очень представляю, куда бы ее здесь можно было бы засунуть))

Comment: Спасибо. Она уже была засунута перед "с". ))

Comment: И правильно сделали, что поставили, поскольку различие есть.  Краны, они разные, а не все с автоматизацией, тем более с необходимой.